Is the Outsider hiding among the people of Dunwall?
There are writings saying THE OUTSIDER WALKS AMONG US on the walls everywhere in the city.
Does that suggest that the Outsider hides among the various NPCs in the missions, possibly through the Possession supernatural power?
In my experience I have not encountered NPCs that were possessed by the Outsider, but I am curious as to what the meaning of this line is.

It's meant metaphorically: this slogan is intended as an expression of the conviction that the Outsider is no longer just observing (or even disinterested or absent), but actively concerned with the common people (compare it, for example, with phrases like "god walks among us" or "they walk among us").
As in real life, the people of Dunwall are increasingly looking to outside supernatural forces now that the rat plague and a regicide and their consequences have them living in fear, anger, and poverty.
The existence of the Outsider, a morally ambiguous god-like entity, is considered the source of all magic in the known world, and would therefore have the power to have initiated or to overthrow the status quo. And even though his worship is considered heresy by authorities (namely the Abbey of the Everyman), it is still very much alive. Written signs like the graffiti you're referring to are a way for people to express themselves anonymously—and spread hope or fear, depending on one's take on the Outsider.
[Spoilers ahead.]
Corvo, Daud, Emily, and Billie have seen the Outsider, and he seemingly can appear before anyone he wants to (usually during dreams and at altars erected in his name), so it's not impossible that others have seen him walk among those unaware of his presence. But I doubt he'd need or even would bother to possess other bodies, as he has an established physical form.
That at least two bearers of the Outsider's mark simultaneously roam the cities of Dunwall and Karnaca is rare, and, since the mark is actually the name of the Outsider, he is, in a sense, present or at least represented.
A direct piece of evidence of how this phrase is interpreted (and likely intended) in-universe, is found in The Outsider Walks Among Us, an article in the (sensationalist) tabloid The Silver Spike encountered in the second game, according to which the writer and like-minded others (in Karnaca, during the "bloodfly concern") are witnessing his presence in the world:

Many of the shrines built to honor [the Outsider] have been disturbed of late, as if recently visited. That figure of myth apparently walks among us, gathering up offerings. Some leave ruin-carved [sic] tokens of bone in the abandoned corners of Karnaca, and others interested in such matter report that, yes, those tokens are gone a night later!
Trust your senses. Do you not taste him in the withered, sickly crabs you boil for dinner? Can you hear his voice in the hum of bloodfly wings? What else could explain our current plight here in Karnaca. Murder in the streets and firing squads as a response. Such times!

This suggests they could mistake the actions of (i.c.) Corvo or Emily (picking up Bone Charms and Runes left and right) as those of the Outsider—and, as explained, they aren't far from the truth. With the title, the author of the article likely intentionally refers to the graffiti, as many people will by now be familiar with the phrase, but the author interprets it as a bad thing.
